# My knee is clicking when I do squats - should I worry?

Tags: running, knees, squats, joints

I remember that I have always, even back in primary school, avoided anything similar to squats as my knees would do an audible 'click' every time I got low enough. It's not painful, or even unpleasant, it's just - annoying, and a bit scary.

I've picked up regular exercises a bit over a year ago and I have been running at least once a week (3 times per week since January) for half a year. I wanted to add squats to my training schedule but I'm a bit worried about the clicking sound - although I noticed that, since I started running, it's much quieter, and does not happen always (it used to click on every deeper move).

Should I worry about it, or just work my way up gradually and it will pass?

Comment: I have the same thing, ever since I remember all my joints click while stretching, including knees, elbows and backbone. Never painful, but rather relaxing feeling accompanying. When I contacted a doctor about that, he just made some test, all of the results were ok, like I was perfectly healthy - I have no idea about the reason, but you can live with that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very first thing to do is to make sure your form is correct.  [Nerd Fitness](http://nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/07/08/why-you-need-squats-in-your-workout-and-how-to-do-them-right/) has a very excellent article on doing squats that you should check out. Here's a short summary, but I definitely recommend reading his full post:

> - Squat down until your thighs are at least parallel to the floor
> - Try not to extend your knees past your toes
> - Don't arch your back
> - Stand with your feet slightly wider than hip-width apart, and point your toes slightly outward

[He also links to a video about the two most common squatting errors](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90dbFDXfL3Q) and how you can correct them, which I recommend you watch.

If you have the option, have a trianer or someone that really knows their squats watch you to ensure proper form. If after trying out his tips the problem still continues, then I suggest you have a medical professional have a look at your knee.

Comment: From what I've been told, the click could just be something sliding over a boney protrusion. Which could be bad over time I imagine.

Comment: I don't see it mentioned in the NerdFitness article, but [your knees should also point outward](http://stronglifts.com/how-to-squat-with-proper-technique-fix-common-problems/), aligned with the toes. Also, here is [why the knees make cracking sounds](http://blogs.menshealth.com/muscle-guy/is-it-bad-that-my-knees-crack-when-i-squat/2011/04/25/).